# Calling SOAP web service with client certificate error - Authentication header received from the server was ''

Tags: vb.net, web-services, ssl, soap, x509certificate2

I am attempting to call a SOAP web service using a client certificate and I am getting the below error message.

**The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.**

Prior to the requirement of securing the web service, I was able to retrieve data with the below code minus the cert code.  I have verified that the cert code correctly retrieves the client cert information from my cert store.  Below the code I have added my app config information as well

Could anyone provide any insight on why I am getting the above error message?  Thanks in advance to anyone that can provide any insight.

```
    Friend Function GetWorkByBAWTS(ByVal sBAWTSLookupName As String, ByVal sUnit As String, ByVal sWorkType As String, ByVal sStatus As String) As ArrayList
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

    Dim sSearchType As X509FindType = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(X509FindType), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("searchtype")), X509FindType)
    Dim sSubjectValue As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("searchvalue")
    Dim sDelimiter As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("delimiter")
    Dim sStoreName As StoreName = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(StoreName), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("storename")), StoreName)
    Dim sStoreLocation As StoreLocation = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(StoreLocation), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("storelocation")), StoreLocation)

    Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = Nothing
    Dim store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)


    Dim certcollection As X509Certificate2Collection = store.Certificates.Find(sSearchType, sSubjectValue, False)
    Dim activecollection As X509Certificate2Collection = certcollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, False)

    cert = certcollection(0)
    store.Close()


    Dim iRetry As Integer = 0
    Dim alWorkItems As New ArrayList
    Dim oResponse As lookupObjectsResponse = Nothing
    Dim oClient As ProcessingServiceClient = New ProcessingServiceClient("ProcessingServicePort")

    oClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert
    oClient.Endpoint.Address = New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://mywebservice:8443/prodapp/ProcessingService?wsdl")

    Dim oRequest As lookupObjects = New lookupObjects()
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest = New lookupObjectsRequest()
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupName = "LKWTSTAT"
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters = New lookupObjectsRequestLookupParameters()


    m_oAuthInfo = New authorizationInfo()
    m_oAuthInfo.userId = "user1"

    oClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user1"
    oClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password"


    Dim oItems As lookupParameter()
    ReDim oItems(2)
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items = oItems
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items(0) = New lookupParameter()
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items(0).name = "businessArea"
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items(0).Value = sUnit
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items(1) = New lookupParameter()
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items(1).name = "type"
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items(1).Value = sWorkType
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items(2) = New lookupParameter()
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items(2).name = "status"
    oRequest.lookupObjectsRequest.lookupParameters.Items(2).Value = sStatus


    oResponse = oClient.lookupObjects(m_oAuthInfo, oRequest)


    If Not oResponse.lookupObjectsResponse1.Items Is Nothing Then
        For Each oWorkItem As workInstance In oResponse.lookupObjectsResponse1.Items
            alWorkItems.Add(oWorkItem)
        Next
    End If
    Return alWorkItems
End Function
```

app.config

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="AWDProcessingServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
              openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
              allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferSize="655360" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"
              messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
              useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <!-- <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="" />
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security> -->
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
            </security> 
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://mywebservice:8443/betaapp/ProcessingService?wsdl"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProcessingServiceBinding"
            contract="PS.ProcessingService" name="AWDProcessingServicePort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
<appSettings>
    *** removed cert info ***
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Check `Authentication` methods in IIS if `Anonymous authentication` is enabled.

Comment: Sorry, for clarification the web service is hosted by a third party and not on IIS.  I will have them check their settings for whatever web server is being used.  However, I am actually passing client certificate information to the web service, so why am I getting the error that client authentication is anonymous?  Also, accessing the wsdl manually through a browser, it does require a certificate to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:  The issue ended up being that the user Id being passed in was disabled.  The id was re-enabled and this corrected my issue.